# How to connect two tables by using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

(Sorry this issue is duplicated. Now, I deleted another issue.)
I'm trying RoR Active Records with Association.
And trying to connect two tables, which is restaurants and restaurant_translations. These are split for multi-language support.

Here's the definition of those two tables.

```
create_table "restaurant_translations", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "id",             limit: 4,     default: 0,  null: false
t.integer  "restaurant_id",  limit: 4
t.string   "restaurantname", limit: 255 
t.string   "address",        limit: 255 
t.string   "tel",            limit: 255 
t.text     "description",    limit: 65535
t.string   "lang",           limit: 255,   default: "", null: false
t.datetime "created_at",                                null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                                null: false
end

create_table "restaurants", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "restaurant_type", limit: 255 
t.string   "genre",           limit: 255 
t.string   "url",             limit: 255 
t.string   "fb",              limit: 255 
t.string   "mailaddr",        limit: 255 
t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
end
```

And the Models.

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :restaurant_translations
end 

class RestaurantTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = 'restaurant_translations'
        belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

And then here's the controller which creates my headache.

```
class RestaurantController < ApplicationController
        def list
                @restaurants = Restaurant.all
                @restaurants = @restaurants.restaurant_translation.find_by(lang: "en")
        end
end
```

So error shows like this. Could you tell me how to write?

[image]

@Pavan 's advice causes some another errors like this.

[image]

BTW, my view is like this. It's .slim file.

```
h1 = t :restraunt_list_title

table
  thead
    tr
      th = t :restraunt_list_type
      th = t :restraunt_list_name
      th = t :restraunt_list_url
      th = t :restraunt_list_genre
      th = t :restraunt_list_addr

  tbody
    - @restaurants.each do |restaurant|
      tr
        td = restaurant.restaurant_type
        td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.first.restaurantname
        td = link_to 'here', restaurant.url
        td = restaurant.genre
        td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.first.address


br
```

Comment: Can you show us a example of your view?

Comment: @Wikiti Thanks for the comment. Modified the issue.

Comment: There's no `restaurantname` column in your translations table.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sorry, I didn't update table definitions. Since I already replaced it, could you check it up again?

Answer (score 2):

> undefined method `restaurant_translation' for
>   Restaurant::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f83832cb498

There are two problems in your code

First, You are calling `.restaurant_translation` which should be `.restaurant_translations` as per your associations.

And the second, you are calling that on *ActiveRecord_Relation* which is a *collection of records*(i.e, `@restaurants`) not a *single instance*.

I would do like below instead to achieve what you wanted.

```
class RestaurantController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @restaurants = Restaurant.includes(:restaurant_translations).where('restaurant_translations.lang = ?', "en").references(:restaurant_translations)
  end
end
```

*Note:*

Your `restaurants` table shouldn't contain the `restaurant_id` by *convention*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed what you told me a while ago, but it won't fix. I'll show you how it turns out.

Comment: Sorry, Replacing the script causes another problem. That's missing column name.